# Member variable cannot be changed by annomyous class

Tags: java, android, android-volley, anonymous-class

I'm writing an application in Android Studio using Java and I got a problem. I have a class like this

```
class MyListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ArrayList<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>(); 

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     databaseServer.addToRequestQueue(new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                DatabaseServerDetails.ELEMENTS_PAGE,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            elements.addAll(Element.extractData(response));
                            System.out.println(elements);-------------->1

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        Log.e("requestJoinDietsWithMeals",   error.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("elementID", elementID + "");
                return params;
            }
        });
        System.out.println(elements); ------------>2
    }


}
```

The problem is that inside the anonymous class (location 1) the elements variable  is changing his content and after that (location 2) the variable remains empty. Why is this happening?  Thank you and have a great day.

Comment: Look at your logs. Which line runs first?

Comment: Have you tried to declare the variable as final

Comment: And yes, you're only defining the callback listener which will most likely run at a later time after the println at (2) has already run

Comment: Glancing at your code, It sort of looks like line 2 could be run before line 1

Comment: Yes. It looks that line 2 runs before 1.

Comment: If i'm not wrong, just local variables needs to be declared as final to be captured in an anonymous class.

Comment: "Yes. It looks that line 2 runs before 1." - Yep, 'cause you're performing an asynchronous operation there. The `addToRequestQueue()` call isn't going to pause until `onResponse()` gets called. Execution immediately proceeds to the next line. Just do whatever you need to with `elements` from `onResponse()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your elements variable is empty in location 2 because the code you run inside the call to database.addToRequestQueue is runned asynchronously.

This means that the function is not executed in the same moment it is called but there is delay.

So what happen is that your user clicks, the onClick event handler is called, the request to the database is added to the queue and right after that you print your empty elements collection, then your request is fullfilled only AFTER an unknown amount of time and your list is populated.

What you want to do is to move all the code that use the collection inside the response listener (location 1).